# Import file.py from folder, along with the other sub-folders

Tags: python-3.x

I have a structure as :

```
- api.py
- reports (folder)
  |_app.py
  |_pages (folder)
    |_page1.py
```

In reports, app.py calls page1.py. I need to execute app.py from api.py. I am trying to "from reports import app" but I get :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'
```

Any ideas on how I can do this? I am new to modules in Python, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Refer to this https://sweetcode.io/python-file-importation-multi-level-directory-modules-packages/

Answer (score 0):

`from reports import app`
That would work if `reports` is a module and `app` is a function inside it. Since `reports` is a folder, this approach wouldn't work. An easy solution would be

```
import sys
sys.path.append('specify path to reports folder')
import app
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add empty `__init__.py` file to your `pages` folder. For more details see [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for/448311)